# ASP.NET - Telerik : Change size Marker

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, dictionary, telerik

I have a small problem with my Markers in Telerik , look:

(I cant post my image)

http://puu.sh/e9fCH/1b594764eb.jpg

How can i change the size of my Makers Because, here, it's really big for my map...

Thx & Cya !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here follows a sample taken from this thread: http://www.telerik.com/forums/change-size-markersmap

```
/* Change font-size of the glyph icon and fix the marker appearance */
.RadMap span.k-marker-pin:before {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: green;
    margin-left: -19px;
    margin-top: -16px;
}

/* Correct the width of the marker element to fix tooltip position */
.RadMap span.k-marker-pin {
    margin-top: -14px;
    height: 14px;
}
```